# My SaveCommand Button isnt working in UWP why?? I use MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

Ok, I've been practicing with MVVM Pattern on UWP, now I've created an object Customer EditableCustomer which is my helper property between my view and my model at my VM.
if my four properties FirstName, LastName, Email and Phone arent nulls or emptys my savecommand button should enable.

but I havent been able to raise my property changes on my EditableCustomer so that way I could Raise my SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged().

this is my code for my view:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.Views.AddEditCustomerView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.Views"
xmlns:viewmodel="using:MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.ViewModel"
xmlns:conv="using:MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.Converters"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:AddEditCustomerViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <conv:ValidationMessageConverter x:Key="ValidationMessageConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="grid1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="10,10,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="First Name:"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="3"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="0">

            <TextBox x:Name="firstNameTextBox"
                     Text="{Binding EditableCustomer.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Margin="3"
                     Height="23"
                     Width="120"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="firstNameErrorMessage"
                       Text="{Binding EditableCustomer.ValidationMessages[FirstName], Converter={StaticResource ValidationMessageConverter}}"
                       Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Text="Last Name:"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="3"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1">

            <TextBox x:Name="lastNameTextBox"
                     Text="{Binding EditableCustomer.LastName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Margin="3"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lastNameErrorMessage"
                       Text="{Binding EditableCustomer.ValidationMessages[LastName], Converter={StaticResource ValidationMessageConverter}}"
                       Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Text="Email:"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="3"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2">

            <TextBox x:Name="emailTextBox"
                     Text="{Binding EditableCustomer.Email, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Margin="3"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="emailErrorMessage"
                       Text="{Binding EditableCustomer.ValidationMessages[Email], Converter={StaticResource ValidationMessageConverter}}"
                       Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Text="Phone:"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="3"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="3"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="3">

            <TextBox x:Name="phoneTextBox"
                     Text="{Binding EditableCustomer.Phone, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Margin="3"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="phoneErrorMessage"
                       Text="{Binding EditableCustomer.ValidationMessages[Phone], Converter={StaticResource ValidationMessageConverter}}"
                       Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="saveCommandButton"
                Content="Save"
                Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="25,5,0,0"
                Width="75"/>

            <Button x:Name="addCommandButton"
                Content="Add"
                Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="25,5,0,0"
                Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=saveCommandButton, Mode=OneWay}"/>

            <Button x:Name="cancelCommandButton"
                    Content="Cancel"
                    Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="25,5,0,0"
                    Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=saveCommandButton, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

As you can see at my textboxes the text property are bind to my EditableCustomer.(propertyName)

my ViewModel is this one:

```
public class AddEditCustomerViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public AddEditCustomerViewModel()
    {
        CancelCommand = new MyCommand(OnCancel);
        SaveCommand = new MyCommand(OnSave, CanSave);
        EditableCustomer = new Customer();
    }

    private Customer _editableCustomer;

    public Customer EditableCustomer
    {
        get
        {
            return _editableCustomer;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _editableCustomer, value);
            SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyCommand CancelCommand { get; private set; }
    public MyCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

    public event Action Done = delegate { };

    private void OnCancel()
    {
        Done();
    }

    private void OnSave()
    {
        Done();
    }

    private bool CanSave()
    {
        if (HasEmptyFields())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private bool HasEmptyFields()
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(EditableCustomer.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(EditableCustomer.LastName)
                        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(EditableCustomer.Phone) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(EditableCustomer.Email);
    }
}
```

All i need to do is to be able to trigger the setter for my EditableCustomer property, but I've been able to do that with it.
what am i missing here??

I see my code and I think that it should be raise everytime each field has text until it becomes true once all my text boxes have text on them.

but nothing happens.

just to understand this is my BindableBase is a class where I apply my INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(member, val))
            return;

        member = val;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can enlight me, meanwhile i'll try to keep digging on this issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` is only called when you set the `EditableCustomer`, but when you modify the values inside that object (ie name, email, etc), nothing is notifying the UI that `SaveCommand` can execute.

If you're going to break up your view models like that, where you have an encapsulated class that manages the input, then it will need to notify the parent view model of changes. Your `AddEditCustomerViewModel` does not know when the properties have changed and cannot `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` accordingly.

---

**Update**

In your case, I would recommend having the view-model route all properties that can be modified by the UI form. For example:

```
public class AddEditCustomerViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _editableCustomer.FirstName; }
        set
        {
            _editableCustomer.FirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstName));

            if (!HasEmptyFields())
            {
                SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your XAML should bind directly to the view-model, not the model:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand now, but I'm kinda new with mvvm how could I notify the parent? Should I place an x:Datatype at grid lvl?

Comment: Added a code sample to help you out a bit. You fill in the rest :)

Comment: Maaaannn!!! Thanks a lot you helped me a lot with it, thanks to this I now feel ready to continue to the next step, that would be unit testing view models, I'm able to RaiseCanExecuteChanged thanks to you example. also i was able to keep client validation in UWP. my sample works perfectly and thanks to MVVM pattern am able to code reuse most of my code. You surely helped me a lot.